# Fixed top navigation + Sticky footer using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem trying to get both a fixed top navigation and a sticky footer to work, without hiding the footer 40px off the bottom. The jquery script i'm using is meant to fix this, but it doesn't. I can't use bootstrap or anything similar. So this is my only option.

The HTML

```
<div id="container">
<nav role="navigation" id="cssmenu">
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="has-sub"><a href="pages/courses.html">Courses</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/courses/media.html"><span>Digital Media</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/courses/webdev.html"><span>Web Development</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/courses/journalism.html"><span>Journalism</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="pages/courses/infocomms.html"><span>Information & Communications</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header role="banner" id="banner">
        <div class="not-fullscreen background" style="background-image:url('http://www.minimit.com/images/picjumbo.com_IMG_6643.jpg');" data-img-width="1600" data-img-height="1064">
            <div class="content-a">
                <div class="content-b">
                    <h1>header1</h1>
                    <h2>header 2</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="content">   


            <main role="main" id="skipnav">

                <p>Intro paragraph</p>




            </main>
    </div>
</div>
    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
        <div class="container2">
        <p>footer</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

</div>
```

The Jquery script -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var footer_height=$("#footer").height();
$("#wrapper").css({
    'padding-bottom' : footer_height
});
});
```

Css can be found [here](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/webdev2/styling/style.css)

The full website can be found [here](http://www.ico.mmu.ac.uk/13143651/webdev2)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use position: fixed; for footer

Comment: Your footer is not in #wrapper but in #container

Comment: you have extra padding for body and #wrapper tags. Which is making it to overflow and bringing the footer to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you can do using css only no need to use jquery

```
#footer {
 bottom: 0;
 position: fixed;

}
nav {
  top : 0;
 position: fixed;

}
```

Comment: That's not quite what i wanted, i still want it at the bottom of the page, i just want it to always be at the bottom, not floating at the bottom

Comment: use flexbox then  check this example 
http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: I tried adding flexbox but that didn't fix anything either

Answer (score 0):

Few things to change:

`body` was having `padding-top:40px;` which is making the body to overflow. So remove that padding from body.

and `#wrapper` need to be:

```
#wrapper {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

remove that jquery part and padding-bottom line from wrapper.

and make `footer` to be `position: fixed;`

[image]

Comment: If you add more content to it, it just makes the footer float in the middle of the page again

Comment: Change the footer position to be fixed. In that case it won't float.

Comment: Now it's just fixed to the bottom of the page, all i want it to do is be at the complete bottom of the page, not seen at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place footer inside wrapper and use position fixed for the footer instead of position absolute; Furthermore, the only reason to use jQuery to calculate the padding is if your footer does not have fixed height (now you use height: 40px). You also need to give to your wrapper padding top = height of your header.

Try this:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: auto;
}
#wrapper { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
/* padding: calculated 0 calculated; */

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The body tag has padding-top: 40px; which is bad styling. So giving padding to wrapper to fit footer is not a good approach

Comment: Bootstrap uses this technique for its sticky header http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/